# Как добавить в форму поиска текст ссылки при нажатии на неё?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Здравствуйте!!! Помогите люди добрые, Есть форма поиска RokAjaxSearch, есть карта рисунка со ссылками, мне надо сделать так чтобы при нажатии на ссылку в форму поиска добавился текст ссылки.

[image: Чертеж с указанием деталей]

Вот и Html карты рисунка

```html
<IMG SRC="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m89Ce.png" WIDTH=209 HEIGHT=137 BORDER=0 ISMAP USEMAP="#m89Ce.png"><MAP NAME="m89Ce.png"><AREA SHAPE="RECT"COORDS="59,29,132,52"HREF="#1011AA"TARGET="_top"><AREA SHAPE="RECT" COORDS="121,85,199,113" HREF="#1132AD" TARGET="_top"></map>
```

При нажатии на номер(ссылку) он должен по задумке попасть в форму поиска, дабы не вводить его вручную

Comment: Все верстается на joomle и в кодинге несилен, немного знаю PhP, CSS, Html. Подкину WMoney за помощь в решении вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Вы не на тот ресурс обратились, если хотите, чтоб за вас задачу решали. 
Вам достаточно прослушивать на клик "area" и вставлять туда куда вам надо.

```js
$('area').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.here').text(this.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<IMG SRC="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m89Ce.png" WIDTH=209 HEIGHT=137 BORDER=0 ISMAP USEMAP="#m89Ce.png"><MAP NAME="m89Ce.png"><AREA SHAPE="RECT"COORDS="59,29,132,52"HREF="#1011AA"TARGET="_top"><AREA SHAPE="RECT" COORDS="121,85,199,113" HREF="#1132AD" TARGET="_top"></MAP>

<div class="here"></div>
```

Вот пример того же скрипта на чистом js

```
const area = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('area'));

area.forEach(el => {
    el.onclick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector('.here').textContent = el.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
  }
})
```

Comment: Я так понимаю необходимо создать *.js с содержимым  $('area').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.here').text(this.getAttribute('href'));
});   и после подключить его и jquery.min.js, просмотрел в инспекторе скрипты подключены. А вот куда <div> class="here"> засунуть что-бы он отображался именно в форме поиска. Чуть не забыл скрипт обрабатывается jquery не надо ли заменить в теле скрипта $ на jQuery(area) ?

Comment: Есть возможность помочь разобраться? Условия ваши

Comment: $ это alias jquery. Я без понятий про какой вы поиск говорите. Вы все время про него говорите, но какой у него класс, id вы не сказали. Вам достаточно поменять .here на нужный класс/id. Учитывая, что вы пользуетесь joomla, я думаю у вас и так jquery подключен.

Comment: Вам надо вставить этот скрипт как угодно, можно написать в файл и подключить, а можно вставить в теги <script></script>